# Action for form tag not rendering correctly in IE10

Tags: c#, forms, master-pages

We have an older website (written in C#.NET 2.0) that uses a master page (site.master). It has a form that until this point has worked on all browsers. However, in IE10, when you hit Submit, you get a Resource Not Found error message. When I did a view page source on the form, I saw that the form tag was being rendered as such:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="/web/web/maillist.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
```

In all other browsers, it correctly renders it as:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="web/maillist.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
```

I'm at a loss to explain why it is duplicating the folder name. Has anyone else dealt with this issue?

thanks

ETA:  So I have a little more information. It seems to be due to the compatibility mode in IE10. In our company, we have it defaulted to "On". If I mess with the little button in the upper-right corner, I can get it to submit. I need to find a way to override this.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this in the past and found that by adding a leading `/` to the action it will prevent the duplication you are seeing.

Your other option is to force IE out of compatibility mode by using the following in your `<head>` tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

However, "edge" mode is not encouraged in production use: (From MSDN)

> It is recommended that Web developers restrict their use of Edge mode to test pages and other non-production uses because of the possible unexpected results of rendering page content in future versions of Windows Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks. I found the "edge" mode in another post here. I can't add a "/" to the action because it is in the Site.Master page and I am not specifying a link because it will be different based on which form the user is on. 

The code on the Site.Master page is:

<form runat="server">

Unless there is a way to do that in the code behind?

Comment: If you don't want to use the meta tag then you can always update the form action in code-behind (in the Master Page). It's a little dirty, but might solve your issue.